# Is structured basis testing different from code/logic coverage testing

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage

When people speak of structured basis testing, do they just mean code coverage or logic coverage testing, or is there another angle to it which covers more than just those principles?

Comment: I don't know. I've never heard of structured basis testing. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Testing Standards](http://www.testingstandards.co.uk)'s [glossary](http://www.testingstandards.co.uk/living_glossary.htm#S), Structured Basic Testing is a technique to design test cases from the logic of the code aiming at maximizing the test coverage. It just seems to be another name for code/logic coverage testing.

The same definition can be found on [Independent Test](http://www.independent-test.com.au/html/glossary.htm) glossary, with a reference to **[BCS SIGIST](http://www.bcs.org/server.php?show=nav.9262)**.

Answer (score 1):

In Code Complete 2 Steve McConnell describes Structured Basis testing as a method of covering all paths with the minimal set of test cases.

Whilst code coverage or logic coverage testing is similar, you may create many more test cases than you would need to cover the same logic with Structured Basis Testing.

Source: Code Complete 2 Structured Basis Testing Pages 505 - 506